# Using Nikon PS-4 bellows to copy 35mm negs

Tags: lens

I want to digitize my old b&w negs, and have an old PS-4 bellows unit to use on my Nikon D5200, an SLR with a DX format sensor. My PS-4 manual predates DX, and shows a table with lenses from 20mm to 85mm and their respective reproduction ratios from 12X down to 1X respectively. I'd think that I want a reproduction ratio of 0.66, so that my 36mm neg width becomes the 24mm sensor width. Does this mean I need to use a lens like 105mm or higher? Or could I use an 80mm enlarging lens, which seems to focus differently because it assumes a bellows will be used?

And why is it that a wide angle lens seems to have a higher reproduction ratio range in that table? At non-macro distances, objects seem smaller when shot via a 20mm lens, so a 1' ruler at 2' would be only 1/2" or so on my sensor while it would be 1" on the sensor if I used a 50mm.

Comment: I guess you have the Nikon bellows PB-4 + the slide copy PS-4 adapter right?

Comment: Since part of your question is based on information contained in a table, could you provide a link or image of that table? Without that information, it is impossible to answer the last part of your question.

Comment: Are you sure about the reproduction ratios you've quited? A 12X magnification is a 12:1 reproduction ratio. On the other hand, a 1:12 reproduction ratio is a 0.0833X (1/12X) magnification factor.

Comment: I used that setup in the past and I did not have any issue even I was using a DX camera (D300). I had to test some settings and  I think the final setup was using a micro Nikkor 55mm f/2.8 (AI-s) and extending the bellow of the PS- 4.

Comment: Here's a link to the manual: http://www.cameramanuals.org/nikon_pdf/nikon_ps-4.pdf